# Move scheduled query to a different project BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, schedule

I have a scheduled query in a project x. I need to move it to project y where i will use a service account to run it.

Is there a way to do that without recreating the query in the new project from scratch so i can keep the run history?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no feature in GCP to migrate scheduled query in Bigquery to a different project. You can [setup directly the service account](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-scheduled#configure_the_service_account_to_run_the_scheduled_query) to run the scheduled query in Project X instead to eliminate the need to migrate scheduled query.